# What to chose for my next project with Amazon Web Services (Linux)? Ruby/Python/other, MySQL/PostgreSQL/other

Tags: python, mysql, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I will soon start a new project with Amazon Web Services, on Linux

They have frameworks available for PHP, Ruby, Python, Java and .Net
http://aws.amazon.com/ruby/
http://aws.amazon.com/python/

I am fluent in PHP and Java, I hate .Net

The project is to have a lot (around 50) Amazon instances connect to a central pile (or decentralized, not sure yet) to have jobs to do, with auto-scaling and such.

This implies there will be a lot of database and communication between the instances.

Also, a lot of the job will be Web related like using another Web service, crawling a website, etc. So I need good JSON/XML support and stuff like SOAP would be nice.

I did all that in PHP once using SQLite and going through Apache, but since we are moving to Amazon, we now have granular control of each node with the command-line and everything, I feel it would be way better with a PostgreSQL database and daemons in Ruby/Python.

What do you think?

MySQL or PostgreSQL?
Rewrite everything that was done in PHP to make better daemons in Ruby or Python?

If not, I will simply convert a lot of the code to use the CLI instead of going through Apache.

I am **very** open to other suggestions

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you have no pressing need for a rewrite, just use your existing codebase. Maybe refactor some things step by step, to see if Ruby, Python or Java suit well for particular problems. Python for example is a perfect glue language, also good for crawling and has native json support since 2.6.